# Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed subset. Show that the groups $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n , \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A)$ and

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed subset. Show that the groups $H_i(\mathbb{R}^n
> , \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A)$ and $H_{i+1}(\mathbb{R}^n ×
> \mathbb{R},(\mathbb{R}^n × \mathbb{R}) \setminus (A × {0}))$ are isomorphic, for all $i \geq 0.$

I am new to homology theory and I am stuck in the problem above. I tried using the $n$-simplices but couldn't get ahead. You may give some hint to begin with.

Comment: What tools do you know in singular homology? You said you tried using simplices; are you familiar with excision and/or Mayer-Vietoris sequences?

Comment: @kamills, Yes Sir, I am familliar with that

Comment: This seems like a problem where Mayer-Vietoris or excision would work out for you. You can reduce this problem to a question about absolute homology if you use the long exact sequence of the pair $(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus A)$ to conclude that $H_k(\Bbb R^n, \Bbb R^n \setminus A) \cong H_{k-1}(\Bbb R^n \setminus A)$. You can do something similar for $(\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R, (\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R) \setminus (A \times 0)).$